# How to make multiple url opener in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a multiple url opener too in HTML and Javascript. I am getting some problems that HTTP links are opening but HTTPS links are not. Can anyone help me with that? Here is the code.

```js
function open_all() {
  var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
  var urls = urls.split('\n');
  var totalno = urls.length;
  var s;
  for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
    s = urls[i];
    if (s) {
      if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://') {
        s = 'http://' + s;
      }
      window.open(s);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <br />
  <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onClick="open_all();">
  <br />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
  <br/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: NO everthing working fine but only https:// link not opening all http:// links are opening for more information see http://www.openmultipleurl.com/ like this its working but its suppose to work like this http://multiurlopener.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because your current code will add `http://` to the start of any URL which starts with `https://`. You need to change your logic so that it checks for `https://` at the start of the URL as well as `http://`. You can also tidy up the logic slightly and use `trim()` to ensure the line wasn't only whitespace. Try this:

```
function open_all() {
    var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        var url = urls[i];
        if (url.trim()) {
            if (s.substr(0,7) != 'http://' && s.substr(0,8) != 'https://') 
                url = 'http://' + url;
            window.open(url);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also note that you may have issues with your browser's popup blocker stopping you spamming the creation of so many windows so quickly.

Comment: Rory McCrossan  Thanks can you explain me that if condition

Comment: It's the same statement as your previous `http://` check, just modified for `https://`. It means 'if the first 7 characters of the string are not 'http://' and the first 8 character are not 'https://'..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add logic in your if condition for https-

```
if(s.substr(0,7)!='http://' && s.substr(0,7)!='https:/')
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  function open_all() {
        debugger;
        var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
        var urls = urls.split('\n');
        var totalno = urls.length;
        var s;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
            s = urls[i];
            if (s) {
                if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://' && s.substr(0, 8) != 'https://')
                    s = 'http://' + s;
                window.open(s);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```