# How to add a delay in URL opener after every URL?

Tags: jquery, html, function

I am working on a URL opener using Javascript. 
Got the code from here. 
https://w3guy.com/build-bulk-url-opener-tool/ 
And also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790031/how-to-make-multiple-url-opener-in-html-and-javascript)

Now, I want to open every URL with a delay of say 3-5 seconds.. How should I do it?

Code (Js).

```
function open_all() {
        debugger;
        var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
        var urls = urls.split('\n');
        var totalno = urls.length;
        var s;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
            s = urls[i];
            if (s) {
                if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://' && s.substr(0, 8) != 'https://')
                    s = 'http://' + s;
                window.open(s);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Code (Form)

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <br />
  <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onClick="open_all();">
  <br />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
  <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: use `setTimeout` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: I suggest you get familiarized with setTimeout JavaScript function. Google it and you will figure it out. This way you will develop your ability to figure out stuff yourself.

Comment: So do you want them *all* to open after a delay, or a sequential delay (ie, first opens after 3 secs, 2nd after 6 etc)

Comment: Yes... @Jamiec.
a sequential delay (ie, first opens after 3 secs, 2nd after 6 etc)